# chrome is not able to run in Selenium Webdriver . i am using selenium 3.0.1 chrome v-54.0

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
public class sikuli {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Screen screen=new Screen();
        //screen.click("//home//exeter//Pictures//googlechrome.png");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","//home//exeter//Documents//chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://mail.google.com");
```

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.24.417424 (c5c5ea873213ee72e3d0929b47482681555340c3) on port 11320
>   Only local connections are allowed.
>   Oct 19, 2016 10:07:22 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
>   Oct 19, 2016 10:08:22 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417424 (c5c5ea873213ee72e3d0929b47482681555340c3),platform=Linux 4.4.0-43-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '350cf60', time: '2016-10-13 10:43:56 -0700'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{message=unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Comment: make it as chromedriver.exe

Comment: The driver executable does not exist: /home/exeter/Documents/chromedriver.exe

Comment: you can give file path like G:\\ravik\\Ravi-Training\\Selenium\\Drivers\\cd\\chromedriver.exe

Comment: Which version of selenium are U using ??? Does it work in latest version ??

Comment: Chrome 54 is... *really* old? Like, late 2016 levels of old?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running on a Linux machine, so "chromedriver" (without .exe) should be fine. Just make sure you have the latest chrome and latest chrome driver versions, and also you have the correct "chromedriver" file (the one on 64 bits).

Answer (score 0):

Please check path is correct for chrome driver version 
https://chromedriver.chromium.org. you need use chrome driver according to which chrome browser version are using

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on windows you need to specify .exe at the end too(Unless you are running on Linux)
On a side note try this https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager. It will automatically download the driver for you based on your browser and OS. Managing the driver manually is just a waste of time in my opinion.